# Static object member initialization with parameters in class

Tags: c++, object, static, initialization, member

I have not found right answer though i tried multiple search in this site. I raise the question again.

Normally, the static object member should be initialized in the source file.

```
//header file
class A{ 
private: 
   static B*  bPoint ;

public: 
    static void init(int argc, char** argv);
  ... 
};

//Source file: 
B A::bPoint = new B()              //Normally, this should OK.
```

But the problem is that default B construction is private and now I have to use another public construction

```
 B(int argc, char** argv);
```

In this case, 
  new B() would give out compilation error..
then how I can initialize the static bPoint in class A?

Comment: What is your problem with private: B() public:  B(int argc, char** argv) ? (PS: Avoid pointers)

Comment: @DieterLücking. The reason of private: B() is that we don't want to create B varibale. E.g, Singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static member should be defined in the source file, but note that you can initialize it with a null pointer at first:

```
// source file:
B* A::bPoint;  // note the pointer to B
```

Then, if your problem is to forward the arguments to `A::init()` to the constructor of `B()`, you could allocate an object for `bPoint` inside `A::init()`:

```
A::init(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bPoint = new B(argc, argv);
}
```